# Blurry windows apps

Tags: windows

How do you debug to find the reason why Windows apps (Terminal, Microsoft Edge and Apps installed using Microsoft Store-but not all) suddenly are blurry like this:

[image]

Other apps are not affected.

Comment: Do you use multiple monitors?

Comment: No, I am just using my laptop

Comment: Have you tried to change the font Windows Terminal is configured to use?

Comment: It's not just Windows Terminal, other apps also, like Microsoft Browser (Edge)

Comment: Does it only affect text or does it also happen to images? Is it only part of the screen? It looks like at the bottom of the terminal window it's still clear. If you move the window, does the blur move with it?

Comment: Update your video drivers?